# Object Mapping With Restkit to core data for MultipleTables

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data, restkit

I am developing one iPad application.For my application I am using Restkit object mapping for get the objetcs from WebApi and Save in my core data.I have 2 tables names Class,Names,. Each tables have separate Fields Example
a)Names :- FirstName,Lastname
b)Class :- ClassA,ClassB,ClassD
The Web Api Returns JSON data like ---

```
{
"status": 200,
"statusMessage": "OK",
"message": "SUCCESS",
"data": {
    "station": {
        "Names": [
            {
               FirstName:"Richard"
               Lastname:"Jecob"
             },
             {
                FirstName:"David"
                Lastname:"philiph"
                }
              ],
            "Class" : [
                  {
                "ClassA": "Noramal",
                 "ClassB":"Average"
             },
           ]
```

I wrote code for one entity mapping Example For Names

```
    NSArray *nameArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:
                    @"firstName",
                    @"lastName",nil];

NSDictionary *nameDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];
NSArray *ideArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"firstName",@"lastName" nil];

NSString *EntityName = @"Names";
NSString *pathPattern = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/data"];
NSString *keyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data.station.Names"];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/data"];

AppDelegate *ad = (TSAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = ad.restKitManagedObjectStore;

RKEntityMapping *mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:EntityName inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:nameArray];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:nameDict];
mapping.identificationAttributes = idArray;
NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx
RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodGET pathPattern:pathPattern keyPath:keyPath statusCodes:statusCodes];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKManagedObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];
operation.managedObjectContext = managedObjectStore.mainQueueManagedObjectContext;
operation.managedObjectCache = managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache;
// This property controls if the objects are persisted in the DB or not.
operation.savesToPersistentStore = YES;
[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
    NSLog(@"The public timeline Tweets: %@", [result array]);
} failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

It is working fine for me when i give one entity .I need to give more than one entity for mapping (Names,Class).I am new in rest kit mapping some one help me to rewrite the above code for more than one object mapping for Class and Names

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create Core Data models and relationships. My suggestion is to divide them for 3 objects: Station, Name and Class. Relationships could be: Station->>Name, Station->Class, where "->>" To-Many and "->" To-One relationships respectively. Don't forget to create reverse relationships. After that create mapping rule and relationship in RestKit. Relationship is created with RKRelationshipMapping object.

Comment: The important info you missed is that you need multiple response descriptor, with different key paths and mappings, if you don't want the 3rd Entity and the relationships.

Comment: @razor28 Thank you for your help.I created multiple response descriptor and solve the problem.